# Blackberry application not getting installed on phone

Tags: blackberry

I am trying to install the application developed by me on Blackberry device. I am using Blackberry Pearl 8100 and desktop manager 4.3.0.17 to load the application.

I am getting the error message as:
`The application cannot be installed because some files are missing`.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you're packaging your application as as ALX file - basically a zip file that includes your COD and an ALX (xml) descriptor file.  Desktop Manager can't install apps just from a COD file (although if you have the JDE installed, you can use "javaloader" to load an app from a COD).

Comment: Hello Marc,actually i am using Eclipse plugin for Blackberry.
I have generated .alx file by right click on project->generate alx file.
I am loading this file through desktop manager->application loader.
I am not getting where i am making mistake.
PLease help.

Comment: I think his point is that you might want to try installing the JDE and try using the command line tool javaloader to see if that makes a difference. (javaloader -u load <name of cod>.cod)

Comment: Exactly - if you can't install the COD from javaloader then you know the problem is somewhere in the generation of the COD file itself (compiling, signing, etc.).  If you CAN install it with javaloader, then the problem lies either with the ALX generation or with Desktop Manager.  Typically during development, people use javaloader to test on the device.

You note that you are using "Desktop Manager 4.3.0.17" - you should try updating to the latest version (4.7) as that will still work with older devices and OS versions, and might be more reliable when loading your app via ALX.

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling device and desktop manager softwares.

I am not sure of this solution,but it might help.

Comment: Hi itsteju,
I have tried reinstallation.
It "did not" work for me.
I have already spent a day in all this stuff...Please help me out with solution.
Thanks for replying.

Comment: I am using Eclipse plugin for BLackberry 
and component package version is 4.5.0

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked that you're cod file is in the same directory as the alx file when you install it?

When do you receive the error, on application startup or when you enter a specific screen?

Are you using any 3rd party software or libraries (e.g. ksoap)?

Comment: Yes both the files are in same folder.
I am not able to move the application to phone.
Getting the error in desktop manager itself.

Comment: Have you checked that you have the correct software on your handset?  e.g. if you've designed you're COD file to use 4.2 and you're phone only has 4.1??

Comment: If I build any other application with same system configuration,it workksssssss ....
I am not getting why this application is giving problem.
I have used standard xml handlers,xml writer,persistent object stores,which is all originally RIM provided...
Please please help....Badly stucked....